# Geodesically complete translation-invariant torsion-free affine connections on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

Let $\nabla$ be a torsionfree affine connection on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is invariant under the group of translations in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

What are necessary and sufficient conditions on $\nabla$ for it to be geodesically complete?

If the previous question is too difficult to settle, perhaps the following one is easier. What is a class (or maybe classes) of geodesically complete such $\nabla$s?

Comment: Translation invariance tells us that in Cartesian coordinates, the Christoffel symbols $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ are constant. The geodesic equations $\ddot \gamma^i + \Gamma^i_{jk} \dot \gamma^j \dot \gamma^k=0$ is then independent of position; so for determining completeness it suffices to study the dynamics of the first-order nonlinear system $\dot V^i + \Gamma^i_{jk} V^j V^k = 0$ for $V(t)=\dot \gamma(t)$. My guess is that any nonzero torsion-free $\Gamma$ will lead to some finite-time blowup, though maybe my intuition's off.

Comment: Yeah, actually, I think there nontrivial solutions, e.g. in two dimensions take the only nonzero components to be $\Gamma^1_{12}=\Gamma^1_{21}.$ Maybe there's some convenient decomposition of 3-tensors that can help canonicalize the cases?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis, yes it is actually the first order homogeneous quadratic system of ODEs that I am really interested in. Though most such systems will have a finite time blow-up, yet there are some interesting classes that are complete. There are some articles in dimensions 2 and 3, but the general dimension $n$ case was not really studied it seems.

Answer (score 1):

One class of translation invariant complete affine connections, in the plane, was discovered by Yeaton Clifton. These are the translation invariant affine connections in the plane whose geodesic flow preserves a translation invariant positive definite quadratic form. One can show (see the upcoming draft of my [Introduction to Cartan geometries](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.14457), which should be on the arxiv tomorrow), that there is a unique one which is not the standard Euclidean connection: the one whose geodesic equations are
$$
0=\ddot{x}+\dot{y}^2,
$$
$$
0=\ddot{y}-\dot{x}\dot{y}.
$$
More generally, to get a translation invariant Riemannian metric to be preserved along the geodesic flow of
$$
0=\ddot{x}^i+\Gamma^i_{jk}\dot{x}^j\dot{x}^k
$$
we can arrange, by linear transformation, that the Riemannian metric is the Euclidean metric, and differentiate $ds^2=(\dot{x}^i)^2$ to see that the connection has precisely to satisfy
$$
0=\Gamma^i_{jk}\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j\dot{x}^k
$$
i.e. the symmetrization of $\Gamma^i_{jk}$ in $ijk$ has to vanish. This ensures completeness clearly.
It does not require that the connection be Levi-Civita, or even torsion free.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was aware of the existence of that family of translation invariant complete affine connections on $\mathbb{R}^n$, with geodesics living on spheres or, more generally, on level sets of positive definite quadratic forms. I didn't know it was originally discovered by Yeaton Clifton, in the planar case. I am wondering if there are other similar families perhaps? What is known for higher $n$'s please?